# API Platform Serialization issue for custom Output

Tags: symfony, serialization, api-platform.com, reset-password

I have created this resource in order to request a password reset token:

```
POST {{api_base_url}}/users/password/reset-request

Payload example 
{
    "email" :"user@example.com"
}
```

Everything works fine but the response doesn't serialize ResetPasswordRequestOutput to show the result. I got this response instead (as User type)

```
{
"@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://dev.api.xxxxxxxxxx.com/docs.jsonld#",
    "hydra": "http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#",
    "token": "ResetPasswordRequestOutput/token"
},
"@type": "User",
"@id": "/users/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
"token": "ORGOsGh01sr8R91J"
}
```

Expected output: (of type: ResetPasswordRequestOutput)

```
{
"@type": "ResetPasswordRequestOutput",
"token": "ORGOsGh01sr8R91J"
}
```

**Code:**

The controller class of the custom operation:

```
final class  ResetPasswordRequest {

private $validator;

private $entityManager;

public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validator, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->validator = $validator;
}

public function __invoke(ResetPasswordRequestInput $data)
{
    $this->validator->validate($data);

    $userRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class);

    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => $data->email]);
    if (!$user) {
        throw new ItemNotFoundException("invalid token");
    }
    if ($user->getStatus() !== UserStatus::ACTIVE) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException("user is inactive");
    }

    $generator = (new Factory())->getGenerator(new Strength(Strength::MEDIUM));
    $token = $generator->generateString(16, 'BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789');
    $user->setToken($token);

    return $user;
}
}
```

---

The data transofrmer that converts User object to ResetPasswordRequestOutput

```
 namespace App\DataTransformer;
    final class ResetPasswordRequestOutputDataTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
    {

        private $normalizer;

        public function __construct(NormalizerInterface $normalizer)
        {
            $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function transform($data, string $to, array $context = [])
        {
            $output = new ResetPasswordRequestOutput();
            $output->token = $data->getToken();

            return $output;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function supportsTransformation($data, string $to, array $context = []): bool
        {
            return ResetPasswordRequestOutput::class === $to && $data instanceof User;
        }
```

---

DTO object that holds input data

```
<?php

namespace App\Dto;



final class ResetPasswordRequestInput
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\Email
     * @Groups({"user:write"})
     */
    public $email;

}
```

---

DTO object that holds output data

```
namespace App\Dto;

final class ResetPasswordRequestOutput
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Groups({"user:read"})
     */
    public $token;

}
```

---

User Entity class with ApiResource annotation (partial) action=reset_password_request

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"user", "user:read"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"user", "user:write"}},
 *     collectionOperations={
 *        "get",
 *        "post",
 *        "reset_password_request" = {
 *              "method"= "POST",
 *              "read"=false,
 *              "path"="/users/password/reset-request",
 *              "controller"=ResetPasswordRequest::class,
 *              "status"=200,
 *              "input"=ResetPasswordRequestInput::class,
 *              "output"=ResetPasswordRequestOutput::class,
 *              "normalization_context"={"jsonld_embed_context"=false}
 *         },
```

Comment: It looks like you're never calling `ResetPasswordRequestOutputDataTransformer` in your code, so it will just return `$user` as a response which is of type `User`

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.
ResetPasswordRequestOutputDataTransformer is called. when i added dump() inside

supportsTransformation ()
 returns true

Comment: Your invoke method requires returning of DTO instead of real entity. That is why original object is serialised since that's what you return to next step in API pipeline. Understand how handling of message resolvers works abd how DTOs transform data you will know.